# XML containing Ampersand, breaks SQL XML Schema validation

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, xml-parsing

I have a stored proc that is receiving XML as an input. A XML Schema Collection within SQL validates the XML received.

One of the items referenced in the XML string is a product code, and this *could* contain an ampersand.  I'm receiving an error when trying to pick up the product code when trying to extract the data.  This is what I'm currently using:

```
DECLARE @cursor CURSOR;
SET @cursor = CURSOR FAST_FORWARD READ_ONLY FOR
                SELECT Quotenbr = COALESCE(items.value('(@quotenbr)[1]', 'varchar(25)'), 'Skipped')
                     , QuotelineItem = COALESCE(items.value('(@quotelineitem)[1]', 'varchar(25)'), 'Skipped')
                     , Branch = COALESCE(items.value('(@branch)[1]', 'varchar(25)'), 'Skipped')
                     , Partnbr = items.value('(@partnbr)[1]','varchar(25)') --Part Number can contain & character, which breaks this - need alternate
                     , Qty = items.value('(@qty)[1]','decimal(9,2)')
                     , Unit = items.value('(@unit)[1]','nvarchar(25)')                  
                FROM @XMLString.nodes('/request/items/item') AS XTbl(items);
OPEN @cursor;

FETCH NEXT FROM @cursor 
 INTO @quotenbr
    , @quotelineitem
    , @Branch
    , @Partnbr
    , @qty
    , @unit;
```

The code fails to correctly handle the Partnbr input.  Is there something I can do for partnbr to not break when the string contains an ampersand?

I'm assuming the schema validation element is swapping the & for '&+amp;' - is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Can you provide a [mre] here.

Comment: You really need to show an example that demonstrates the breakage, including data. What I'm expecting here is that whatever generates the source "XML" doesn't correctly serialize `&amp;` entities when encountering `&` characters in raw data.